# Bf4 problem with phantom prospect

Tags: battlefield-4, ps4

I bought premium not on my main account and it will not let me put in the code on battlelog. What do I need to do to be able to put in the code?

Comment: Are you getting the 'Phase 4, physical access locked' message on the Phantom text console?

Comment: Yes, that s exactly what it says, but i cant put in the code for any phase

Answer (score 1):

You have to buy Premium. The Phantom-Programm is for premium members only.

[Complete description to get all the awesome phantom stuff](http://mp1st.com/2014/11/25/mp1st-reader-blog-ultimate-guide-completing-battlefield-4s-phantom-program/#.VkI8mPkveUk)

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to go to YouTube.com and follow JackFrags for these questions.  He usually has a really easy step-by-step on how to unlock the videos.

I found this one for you:

[JackFrags Unlock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5qW9mHNHIE)

Based off of several special pictographs that were found in Dragon's Teeth map pack (eight of which), They placed these in a 64 hexagram table that gives each picture a set of numbers.  These numbers correspond with the Fibonacci sequence.  Changing them from numbers to tri-pictographs then to unicode decimals, you get a sent of numbers (lots of numbers I won't get into).  Getting those numbers, you have to changed them from Largest to smallest.

So you get these long Unicode Decimals, DICE dropped a hit stating that "X marks the spot.  The Greek one". Well inside the Battlelog Password screen, the Greek X (CHI) was given a number (7.something).

Well, you Multiple the Unicode Decimal (which we'll call U) and multiple CHI^i++:

U*x^0 + U*x^1 + ... U*x^7
Which equals 24344241893.stuff

In the Password screen, they have a parameter called (max, floor).  We used max earlier to change the numbers to start largest to smallest.  Now we use the floor method to drop all the numbers after the decimal point.

So, Long story short, the answer is 24344241893.  Enter that into Battlelog and you'll unlock the next phantom mission.

Also, from Battlelog itself, a forum dedicated to getting Phase 4.

[Battlelog Help](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/forum/threadview/2955064786311895850/)

Granted this is from November 11th.  But this should still apply.

How to access the Phantom Terminal

1)Make sure you have premium on your account

2)Go to the LEADERBOARDS page

3)Scroll to the bottom of the page

4)Click the little skull icon to show the Phantom Terminal

Previous Phantom Program Passwords

Phase 1: bumpinthenight

Phase 2: epic dream worlds

Phase 3: 24344241893

Comment: Please summarize the video in your answer.  That way, if the video ever gets deleted, your answer is still valid.

Comment: How about quit downvoting and offer advice instead.  Cute.

Comment: The two actions are not mutually exclusive.  Indeed, downvoting is considered more important than commenting is.  Either way, now that you've summarized the video, I removed my downvote.

Comment: They are mutually exclusive.  Instead of being a random downvoter (I understand why we have a downvote system), instead, teach, instruct on how to better an answer.  That's the point of comments.  This is a forum to better ones knowledge.  Instruction and help are what this forum is for.

Comment: No, actually, that's not what StackExchange is about at all.  It's about building a repository of high quality knowledge.  Instruction and help are side effects of building that knowledge, and that's why you can both downvote, *and* comment (or not, as the voter sees fit).  At no point is the primary focus on instruction *or* help.  If that's what you believe SE is about, you're not going to have a very good experience here, I'm afraid.

Comment: That's exactly what this is about.  One asks a question to get an answer.  That's instruction.

Comment: The asker has indicated he's on phase 4 and it would appear he does not know what to do next.

Comment: I wonder if that means asking about how to unlock the bow?  I just wished the OP was more specific.  I can add the bow information if needed.